# Issue with asmx webservice Date object

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm parsing `Date` object to web service using `java script` as below.

```
HRA_Create.HelloWorld(new Date("2013-07-08 00:00:00"));
```

but when i check this `Date` in `asmx WebMethod`, display as `7/7/2013 6:00:00 PM`.

I debug my app and see the value as below.

```
Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
```

What could be the error ? how can i solve this ?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(DateTime dt)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString());

        return dt.ToString();
    }
```

**Java Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callServer() {
        HRA_Create.HelloWorld(new Date("2013-07-08 00:00:00"));
    }
</script>
```

**ScriptManager**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/HRA_Create.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

**Java Script Call**

```
<a href="javascript:callServer()">Call Server</a>
```

Comment: Both dates are different, you might want to check your code, it is not formatting issue.

Comment: @Nil Sorry. my copy paste issue. i have updated my post. return value is `7/7/2013 6:00:00 PM`.

Comment: 2013-07-08 and 7/7/2013 are different, is that correct?

Comment: @Nil no it is not correct. that is the problem. i'm passing `2013-07-08` to `WebMethod` and it returns `7/7/2013`. this is not correct. i need to return passed value from `WebMethod`.

Comment: Post your webmethod code.

Comment: @Nil i have updated my post with `WebMethod` code.

Comment: Can this be some kind of time offset problem? There is a precise six hours difference between the values.

Comment: Also post your complete code for calling webservice method.

Comment: @Nil i have updated my post with codes.

Comment: @mortb I'm returning passed value without any formatting. so i can't think this is due to some kind of time offset problem.

Comment: Did you check in console what date is being returned? I checked your code at my end and it works perfect and returns me the correct date.

Comment: @Nil I have checked. but me, it is not returned correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of the following ISO 8601 compliant [W3C formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime):

```
Year:
   YYYY (eg 1997)
Year and month:
   YYYY-MM (eg 1997-07)
Complete date:
   YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16)
Complete date plus hours and minutes:
   YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00)
Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds:
   YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
Complete date plus hours, minutes, seconds and a decimal fraction of a second
   YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)

where:

YYYY = four-digit year
MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

In your example, any of the following should send the correct date:

```
HRA_Create.HelloWorld(new Date("2013-07-08T00:00:00Z"));
HRA_Create.HelloWorld(new Date("2013-07-08"))
```